# Scala - Using guice multibinder on a generic interface fails

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

I have the following interface:

```
trait Subject[T] {
   def fetch() :Future[Option[T]]
}
```

And class:

```
class ChildSubject@Inject()(dao:Dao) extends Subject[String]{
   def fetch(): Future[Option[String]] ={
       dao.find("10").map{ name => Some(name) 
   }     
}
```

And a module:

```
class SubjectModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule{
    override def configure(): Unit = {
          val subMulti = ScalaMultibinder.newSetBinder[Subject](binder)
          subMulti.addBinding.to[ChildSubject]
    }
}
```

And I try to inject this Set:

```
@Singleton
class SomeClass @Inject()(subjects: Set[Subject]){
    subjects.map{
      //do somthing
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[kinds    
of the type arguments (com.test.Subject) do not conform to the expected  
kinds of the type parameters (type T).
com.test.Subject's type parameters do not match type T's expected  
parameters:
trait Subject has one type parameter, but type T has none]
```

Any idea??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `new TypeLiteral<Subject<String>>()` for binding - generically typed interface like `Subject<T>` in Guice from Java.  It's very likely that Scala requires the same in some form.

Something like this may work:

```
class SubjectModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule{
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    val subMulti = ScalaMultibinder.newSetBinder[Subject[String]](binder)
    subMulti.addBinding.to[ChildSubject]
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I may have several classes with different types for example: ChildOne extends Subject[Int], and ChildTwo extends Subject[String], so I can't bind it specifically to String. Make sense?

Comment: @Tomer yep.  I see where you are going here.  You need the multibinder to provide the type parameter in the addBinding step, but how? Hmm

Comment: You need to be able to partially apply the type constructor. I know that in Haskell. Not sure how to do it in Scala.

Comment: What type do you expect the bound set to have?

Comment: @TavianBarnes I expect it to be Set[Subject]